# listview binding selectedItems

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm able to bind to the ItemSource no problem.

What I'm unable to do is bring back the SelectedItems and have them show in the listView.

I'd like to be able to have the listView display the checked items if it is found in the assignedChores collection.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<ListView x:Name="choreList" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1"     
Margin="401,322,613,150" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMemberPath="Summary"     
ItemsSource="{Binding choreList, Mode=OneWay}"     
SelectedItem = "{Binding personSingle.assignedChores, Mode=TwoWay}"     
SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="choreList_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: Is `personSingle.assignedChores` a `List<T>` or an object?

Answer (score 4):

`ListView` has `SelectedItems` property which is type of `IList<T>` but it's read only, so you can't bind it. `SelectedItem` can be bound to an `object` not to the `List<T>`.

You have only option, that's you need to bind `ListViewItem`'s `IsSelected` property with ViewModel's property.

```csharp
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        ListViewItem listItem = element as ListViewItem;           
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Source = item;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelectedFromViewModel");
        listItem.SetBinding(ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there another control that will take bindings for lists without having to roll my own?

Comment: No it's not because all the view controls are derived from `ListViewbase` class.

Comment: so everyone that wants to bind a list to a listview has to roll their own?  Seems like MSFT should add that functionality to the control no?  Oh well I will roll my own like you suggest and see where that goes.

Comment: Might be helpful, [Managing Multiple selection in View Model (.NET Metro Style Apps)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412417/Managing-Multiple-selection-in-View-Model-NET-Metr)

Comment: Look at this: [It's another way to solve the problem](http://igrali.com/2015/03/05/pass-listview-selecteditems-to-viewmodel-in-universal-apps/)

Comment: Isn't this defeating the point of MVVM? - Since now the view directly couples with the viewmodel (it needs a specificied member to exist).

Comment: @paul23 this answer is not specifically for MVVM.